# selecting records from a table where a given date falls between 2 dates (columns) from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

EDIT -----------------

I'm going to try to clarify.

I have this table:

[image]

A user will input a start date and an end date.

Let's say the user inputs 2011-10-21 for the start and 2011-12-18 for the end.

This will bring back all the records:

[image]

But what if the user inputs 2011-10-22 and 2011-12-18?

The 2011-10-22 is BETWEEN the date range of the FIRST ROW 2011-10-21 (start) & 2011-10-23 (end).

SINCE IT IS BETWEEN THE DATE RANGE OF THE FIRST RECORD, I WANT to return that row as well. I DO NOT WANT TO EXCLUDE IT.

So if if I run a query like this:

select * from table where PayPeriodStart between '2011-10-22' and '2011-12-18'

I WANT to see this:

[image]

and NOT this:

[image]

PLEASE NOTE... the user can enter in any start or end date and it'll be at least 1 week.

So they can pick 2011-11-09 (start) and 2011-12-04 (end) for example.

Comment: Are you passing in a given date and want the records where that passed in date is between PayPeriodStart and PayPeriodEnd?

Comment: I pass in the start date and the end date. I want to return all the records in the table where the dates fall under the passed in parameters EVEN if there is overlapping such as the example I gave.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but maybe where PayPeriodStart > YourStartDateVariable OR PayPeriodEnd > YourEndDateVariable??

Comment: hang on. im gonna try to make it clearer.

Comment: if you ask date `PayPeriodStart between '2011-10-22' AND '2011-12-10' ` `PayPeriodStart = 2011-10-21` is `excluded` so there no problem. I think I don't understand what you need...

Comment: MacKentoch, I DONT want to exclude it. IF that's the case, how do I capture that record as well??

Comment: I edited the OP to make it clearer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the search criteria to return the rows where the period *start date* is before the *end date criteria* and the period *end date* is after the *start date criteria*.  In other words:

```
declare @Table table (PayPeriodStart smalldatetime, PayPeriodEnd smalldatetime)

insert into @Table (PayPeriodStart, PayPeriodEnd)
select '2010-01-01', '2010-12-31' -- test before the criteria; is not returned
union select '2011-10-21', '2011-10-23' -- overlaps start date; is returned
union select '2011-10-24', '2011-11-06' -- fully in date range; is returned
union select '2011-11-07', '2011-11-20' -- fully in date range; is returned
union select '2011-11-21', '2011-12-04' -- fully in date range; is returned
union select '2011-12-05', '2011-12-18' -- overlaps end date; is returned
union select '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31' -- test after the criteria; is not returned

-- This yields all but the first row
select * from @Table where PayPeriodStart between '2011-10-22' AND '2011-12-10'

-- This will yield all the rows that overlap the search criteria
select * from @Table
where PayPeriodStart <= '2011-12-10' -- the end search date
and PayPeriodEnd >= '2011-10-22' -- the start search date
```

Comment: I edited the OP to make it clearer. See if it helps.

Comment: Yes.  Did you try the query?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for all records that are valid between '2011-10-22' AND '2011-12-10' , this is the query you should use

```
select * from table where ('2011-10-22' >= PayPeriodStart AND '2011-10-22' <= PayPeriodEnd) Or ('2011-10-22' < PayPeriodStart AND '2011-12-10' > PayPeriodEnd)
```

Comment: I edited the OP to make it clearer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for

```
select * from table where '2011-10-22' between PayPeriodStart AND PayPeriodEnd 
AND '2011-12-10' between PayPeriodStart AND PayPeriodEnd
```

If you want to get data based on first of the month and last of the month or for fixed time interval like 30 day window, you may have to use DateAdd, DateDiff functions to calculate dates.

Following example is based on FirstOfTheMonth, LastOfTheMonth calculation
your reference data

```
declare @refDate date = getdate()

select @min = dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, @refDate), 0) -- First of the month
, @max = dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, @refDate) + 1, 0)) --Last of the month
```

Comment: I edited the OP to make it clearer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been a fan of the between syntax for the edge case reason, so I tend to use this syntax instead:

```
select * from table where ('2011-10-22' <= PayPeriodStart AND PayPeriodStart <= '2011-12-10')
```

Same end result, but I can ensure I include the boundaries as needed.

Comment: Caveat: I am not a SQL Server admin, so I don't know the performance implications between the two statements. That said, it gets the job done. :)

Comment: What is the edge case? BETWEEN is inclusive on both lower and upper bound.

Comment: I edited the OP to make it clearer. See if it helps.